# How can I achieve a mix between a gradient and a picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, corel-draw

[image: gradient-bg]
[image: color stripes bg]

How can I achieve a mix like the following image from these 2 images so I can export it and use it as a background image for a text:

[image]

I've tried to use the gradient image as a background and as a second layer, the color stripes image, then apply some transparency on it, but the colors are too faded and the effect is not the same like in the text.

Any software usage is welcome, but it would be nice to have some quick steps on how can I reproduce this on Photoshop, Ilustrator, Corel or others.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd probably need/want to do it using some kind of mask. In more recent Photoshop versions you can just [form a clipping mask with a layer and text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyKdkrYvJLU), but on an earlier version or another application or a more general/old school method would be to basically just make a selection out of the text and use that as a cookie-cutter on the gradient layer, to get rid of excess.

Comment: I can skip entirely the text. I just need the whole picture in the end, then I'll use CSS on web to aply the picture over the text. But first, I need the image

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake... Didn't it read carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Photoshop . . .

If you want a stronger effect, you should probably experiment with layer blending modes. It's difficult to make a specific suggestion since I can't be sure what exactly you actually want or what you think might be acceptable. There are many layer blending modes to choose from, try them all out! You can also reduce the layer opacity if the effect is too strong.

But anyway here's an example using "Linear Light" at full opacity

[image]

Another with "Screen" and Opacity at 71%.

[image]

And with "Lighten" at full opacity

[image]

It's also possible to add adjustment layers to modify the colours if they've gone a bit dull. For example here's "Screen" layer blending mode at 100% opacity, but with a Vibrance layer adjustment above it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use **GIMP**, you can follow instructions in link: [example of gradient overlay in gimp](https://www.bettertechtips.com/gimp-tutorials/add-gradient-overlay-gimp/)

A different example can be found using **Inkscape** instead GIMP on this link: [mesh gradient background using inkscape](https://logosbynick.com/inkscape-mesh-gradient-background/)

Finally you can consider using **Krita** following instructions in: [How to draw a sunset painting – Easy step by step Krita](https://raghukamath.com/how-to-draw-sunset-painting-krita-tutorial/)

I hope you enjoy using open-source graphic design alternatives :)